# Remove some columns from a table in Google sheets

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I have different columns and I am trying to get the same information but removing some columns.

Is there a way to do this with a unique formula?

The goal to choose the resultants columns, it can be A, B, E or B, D, E, depending what you want.

I've tried with index and putting several values in columns (between {}) but it didn't work, neither with filter.

From this:

```
  A        B      C        D         E

Italy      1      a      apple      cat
France     2      b      pear       dog
Spain      3      c      banana     bird
```

to this:

```
Italy      a       apple
France     b       pear
Spain      c      banana
```

Comment: Please read How to ask and update your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(A:E; MOD(COLUMN(A:E)-1; 2)=0)
```

---

### update

```
=IF(G1="ABE"; {A:A\B:B\E:E}; {B:B\D:D\E:E})
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I've updated the post. Sorry for not being clear from the beginning

Comment: Thanks, it work but it appears all in one column. For more info, I've Spanish keyboard where I have to use `;` instead of `,`

Comment: @AntorCha answer updated use: `=IF(G1="ABE"; {A:A\B:B\E:E}; {B:B\D:D\E:E})`